# admin.messaging().sendToDevice() is NOT running. NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to send notification to a device using firebase-admin sdk and node.js. admin.messaging().sendToDevice() is not running. If anyone else faced this problem, please help me.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

let serviceAccount = require("./cloudmessaging-XXXX-firebase-adminsdk-7rsej-15465a00ba.json");


if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://cloudmessaging-XXXX.firebaseio.com"
    });
}

let registrationToken = regToken;

let payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "Account Deposit",
      body: "A deposit to your savings account has just cleared."
    }
  };

let options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 *24
};

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload, options)
.then(function(response) {
   console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response)
})
.catch(function(err) {
   console.log("Error occured", err)
})
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: i don't get errors. code just doesn't run.

Comment: have you tried executing the file with node? Please describe what you do in order to run the code.

Comment: @Sargsyan Miqayel after 3 years... what solution did you find to solve this?